# What is the concept of Database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I want to know the concept of database in Android. As I understand that using `SQLite database` we can make , update database but I am unable to understand that how the `sign-in` option will be added to  `Android app`. Will it be an app that will be work as a server? And the data of login user will come from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the way you design your app. Usually, the sign-in feature is done by providing an option to enter the sign-in credentials in your app, and the server verifies the data that is entered in your app. You don't want to store the entire database on your app, as it is safer within your server. Again, depends on how you design the app.

Comment: Perfect. It gave me direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is embedded into every Android device. Using an SQLite database in Android does not require a setup procedure or administration of the database

`onCreate()` - is called by the framework if the database is accessed but not yet created.

`onUpgrade()` - called if the database version is increased in your application code. This method allows you to update an existing database schema or to drop the existing database and recreate it via the `onCreate()` method.